# Excel - Formula required for confitional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have been going round in circles with the following for days but cant find anything that works...I need the following to appear red through conditional formatting but I can’t work it out...

> Needs to be completed in “Emergency  4hr” and it was completed in “0 Days 12 Hours 23 Minutes”

As it was completed in over 4 hours this would need to be marked as red

> Needs to be completed in “Critical 5 days” and it was completed in “17 Days 5 Hours 29 Minutes”

As it was completed in over 5 days this would need to be marked as red.

If anyone could help this would be great.

Many Thanks 
Paula

Comment: The color depends on the words 'Emergency' and 'critical' ?

Comment: I suppose it could they are all different I never thought of that...

Comment: Can you post an upload of the sheet or even a screenshot of what your inputs are and the desired outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look into VBA for this.